# swap two variables. which way is faster?

Tags: algorithm

Let's say we have two integers a and b. which way is faster for swapping their values?

```
c=a;
a=b;
b=c;//(edited typo)
```

or

```
a=a+b;
b=a-b;
a=a-b;
```

or bitwise xor

```
a=a^b;
b=a^b;
a=a^b;
```

I'll test its performance differences when I'll be able but I'd like to know it now. Is it bitwise?

Comment: first one should be fastest, since it no need to calculate anything

Comment: First one, only the assignment is stored.

Comment: There is only one way to know which is the fastest, and is measuring. Write a test program than runs your swapping alternatives inside a for loop and average the execution time on every iteration

Comment: There are languages allowing (a, b) = (b, a). There are cost measures like how many 2-input nand-gates are required, how many levels of delay involved (& how many clock cycles, if synchronous)(time)(, how many inputs+outputs change level (energy)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot quantify the speed of an algorithm independent of the program language, the compiler and the platform on which it is run.  An algorithm is a mathematical abstraction.

Having said that:

- for a typical programming language,
- and a typical compiler, and
- a typical execution platform,

the first version will *typically* be faster because it will typically compile to fewer native instructions that take less clock cycles to execute.  The first version only requires load and save operations.  The other two versions have (at least) the same number of loads and saves, and some additional arithmetic or bit manipulation instructions.

However, even that is not cut-and-dry.

The 2nd and 3rd examples are performing the swap without using a temporary variable.  This is something you might do if using an extra temporary variable was expensive.  This might happen on a machine which didn't provide enough general purpose registers, and the relative cost of loading / saving to memory was large.  In some circumstances, the native code equivalents could be optimal.

However ... and this is the real point ... the best strategy is to leave this kind of decision to the compiler.  Unless you are prepared to put a huge amount of effort into micro-optimizing, the compiler is likely to be able to a better job than you can.  Indeed, writing code in "cunning ways" is liable to make it harder for the compiler to optimize.  (In the 3rd case for example, the compiler would need to figure out that that sequence is actually swapping 2 variables before it can substitute the optimal instruction sequence.  Chances are that the optimizer won't be able to do that.)

Comment: thx for all the answers. I asked my friend to test. He tested it on c++ and avg time of case #1 was ~15% lower than other 2(they were almost equal)

Comment: @FiftyStars - without examining the code he used to test it, we cannot be sure that those numbers are meaningful.  However they do align with my expectations.

Comment: thanks, i understand that it can vary in different code. It was a noob's theory question to skilled community. I dont know why but i was sure that bitwise is fastest -_- shame on me. I know how keywords work and i always was familiar with simple programming in different languages. I just dont understand how it all works underneath the keywords and operators yet

Comment: @FiftyStars: This wikipedia article gives some [reasons for avoiding XOR swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice).